# How to change text color with textTheme

Tags: flutter, dart, text, colors

I'm trying to make an android application using flutter from the tutorial, and when I want to change the color of the text according to the tutorial by means of :

```
children: [
  text(
    'Hi Yoikers!',
    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
  ),
],
```

The program error :

```
The method 'copyWith' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').
```

Can you guys help me with this code, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

An Addition to the above answer try using '?'

```
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall?.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with null check:

```
style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall!.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to address 2 issues here (possible solutions too).

1. Theme

That usually happens when you haven’t explicitly provided `theme` / `darkTheme` in `MaterialApp`.

You can optionally provide `Theme()` widget wrapped around the `Text` widget you have in your code right now. Also make sure you have a `Scaffold`. Remember this theme would be scoped to the `Text` widget only.

```
    Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
              /// define the ones you will invoke 
               headlineSmall: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                   )
                ),
            ),
       child: Text(
                'Hi Yoikers!',
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
                ),
      ),
```

2. Null aware

To avoid getting run-time errors add `?` before invoking `copyWith()` as suggested by an other answer (and Flutter in console). This would mean it copies your specified values only if there exists a definition to copy with. In other words it would ignore your specs and use defaults without throwing errors.

For more clarifications, provide  more code, and add a comment!